# How to concatenate data from document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, forms

I have two text fields in an html form with id 'co_addrcheck' and 'usrad_co_addr'. I tried concatenating the two values and copy that to another text field. I tried using the following code but the new text has an 'undefined' value.

```
var loc = document.getElementById('co_addrcheck');
var home = document.getElementById('usrad_co_addr');
```

Neither

```
var post2 = loc  + home;
```

nor

```
var post2 = loc.value  + home.value;
```

works.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do the elements exist at the time you're calling this script? Your second line (with .value) is correct assuming that the two elements are presents. Try logging them separately.

Comment: How do you copy the value to the other text field? You need to say `document.getElementById("yourotherfieldid").value = post2`.

Comment: Yes, they are both non-empty. Yet i still get the 'undefined' value

Comment: @nnnnnn var outpt = document.getElementById('usrad_co_addr'); and then outpt.value = post2;

Comment: Well that should work assuming you have no typos in the IDs and the script is _after_ the fields in the page source or in a document.ready or onload or other event handler that runs after the fields have been parsed. Try putting in a `console.log(loc.value);` or `alert(loc.value)` and the same for `home.value` to check what you're getting before the concatenation.

Comment: seems like its a problem with the copy. outpt.value=home.value works but post2=home.value output is blank .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're text inputs, you should use the "value" property,

```
var post2 = loc.value  + home.value;
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Second one should be working. And best advice is to enclose within try/catch and see the error message.